# Angular data not loading

Tags: angular, http, web-services, rxjs5

Angular also goes into the "first" place when I get data from the service. However, without clicking any button on the page, it does not enter the place where I write "second".

```
 GetAllVessels(){ 
      alert('first');
   this.AllVessels=this.http.get<Vessel[]>(this.baseUrl+'Vessel/GetAllVessels',httpOptions).pipe(
   map((result: Vessel[]) => {
     console.log(result);
     alert('second');
   return result;
   })
   );
```

Comment: Haven't you asked something similar already? Without showing where you call `GetAllVessels` we can't help you.

Comment: there is no call to `subscribe` method

Answer (score 0):

1. Subscribe to the observable returned by `http.get()` calling `.subscribe()` on it
2. Assign the response to `this.AllVessels` inside the `.subscribe()` method
3. Do not store the return value of `http.get()` unless you really intend to store the subscription reference

Try this -

```js
GetAllVessels() {
        alert('first');
        this.http.get<Vessel[]>(this.baseUrl + 'Vessel/GetAllVessels', httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                map((result: Vessel[]) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    alert('second');
                    return result;
                }))
            .subscribe(
                p => this.AllVessels = p,
                e => console.log(e)
            );
    }
```

which can actually be cleaned up to this -

```js
GetAllVessels() {
        this.http.get<Vessel[]>(this.baseUrl + 'Vessel/GetAllVessels', httpOptions)
            .subscribe(
                p => this.AllVessels = p,
                e => console.log(e)
            );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The data is uploaded to the console. However, another process, that is, the page still does not load without clicking a button.

Comment: After capturing the data, I have to click somewhere to see it on the page. That's when he fills the table.

Comment: @Gunseli If the data loading issue is solved, then post another question for the display issue. Because that issue might depend on different factor which are not part of data loading issue (for example, how your table is implemented).